# Thunderbird accounts disappeared

Tags: thunderbird

I'm having a critical problem with Thunderbird. Yesterday all my acount suddenly disappeared from TB GUI (it seems that they still are on my home).

I tried this : [Recovering a profile that suddenly disappeared](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Recovering_a_profile_that_suddenly_disappeared) § Lost Profile and §Recovering data from your old profile. But no success.

I'm having that messages in the TB console :`

```
---------------------
WITH Extensions and Plugin activated
Horodatage : 05/11/2013 09:36:05
Erreur : TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined
Fichier Source : resource://calendar/modules/calUtils.jsm -> file:///{home}/extensions/%7Be2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103%7D/calendar-js/calUtils.js
Ligne : 22

Horodatage : 05/11/2013 09:36:05
Erreur : TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined
Fichier Source : resource://calendar/modules/calUtils.jsm -> file:///{home}/extensions/%7Be2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103%7D/calendar-js/calUtils.js
Ligne : 22

Horodatage : 05/11/2013 09:36:05
Erreur : TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined
Fichier Source : resource://calendar/modules/calUtils.jsm -> file:///{home}/extensions/%7Be2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103%7D/calendar-js/calUtils.js
Ligne : 22

Horodatage : 05/11/2013 09:36:05
Erreur : TypeError: Components.classes[cid] is undefined
Fichier Source : resource://calendar/modules/calUtils.jsm -> file:///{home}/extensions/%7Be2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103%7D/calendar-js/calUtils.js
Ligne : 22

Horodatage : 05/11/2013 09:36:05
Erreur : NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570016 (NS_ERROR_XPC_GS_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.getService]
Fichier Source : resource://calendar/modules/calUtils.jsm -> file:///{home}/extensions/%7Be2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103%7D/calendar-js/calUtils.js
Ligne : 98

Failed to load native module at path '/{home}/extensions/{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}/components/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/libcalbasecomps.so': (80004005) /usr/lib/thunderbird/libxul.so: version `xul24.0' not found (required by /{home}/extensions/{e2fda1a4-762b-4020-b5ad-a41df1933103}/components/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/libcalbasecomps.so)


-----------------------
Safe mode // All plugins deactivated

While creating services from category 'profile-after-change', could not create service for entry 'Disk Space Watcher Service', contract ID '@mozilla.org/toolkit/disk-space-watcher;1'

Timestamp: 05/11/2013 09:46:59
Error: TypeError: this._sort[0] is undefined
Source File: resource://gre/modules/dbViewWrapper.js
Line: 1424
```

Note that I get that problem with TB24.0 (it was yesterday morning). Since TB has been updated to 24.1, I updated but no changes.

Comment: please come back tomorrow and click the tick button next to your answer to close the thread.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

The cause was that the file prefs.js was renamed by an application (Ubuntu One, update or may be during a crash) in prefs-1.js.

Each time I launched TB, TB was creating a new empty prefs.js. So that was why every thing looked empty.

+